# How to reset a user's LDAP password?

Tags: php, passwords, ldap

I am building a simple webpage to allow users to manage their LDAP passwords. I have successfully built a script that allows a user to change their LDAP password, however, I am stuck on a script that would reset their password.

Here is the code I am using to reset the password:

```
// connect to the ldap server
$connection = ldap_connect($server) or die('Cannot connect to LDAP server');

// bind to the ldap server
if(!ldap_bind($connection, $bindDn, $bindPassword)) {
  echo 'Cannot bind to LDAP server<br>';
}

// get the user dn
$userSearch = ldap_search($connection, $baseDn,"(|(uid=$username))");
$userEntry = ldap_first_entry($connection, $userSearch);
$userDn = ldap_get_dn($connection, $userEntry);

// make up a fake password
$chars = 'qwrtyipsdfgghjklzxcvbnmQWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@#$%^&*-=_+",.?';
$passwordLength = 12;
$password = '';

// create the fake password
for($i = 0; $i < $passwordLength; $i++) {
  $password .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars))];
}

// now change the password
$encodedPassword = '{SHA}'.base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($password)));

if(@ldap_mod_replace($connection, $userDn, array('userPassword' => $encodedPassword)) === false) {
    echo ldap_error($connection);
}

// mail the user their new password
```

The result of this code being run is

```
Insufficient access
```

Which is the result of the ldap_mod_replace command.

The only difference between this code and the code I use to change a user's password is that I bind as the user with their password.

Obviously, I cannot do that on a user that has forgotten their password.

I do not manage the LDAP installation nor do I know anything about managing one. Is the issue that the user I bind with initially is not set up to change just anyone's password?

If that is the case, what do I need to tell my sys admin to do?

If not, what is the problem?

Comment: You need to [require some more access](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) to the groups for which you want to reset (=change) the password.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not know anything about the administration side of LDAP. Can you elaborate a bit more so I can rely the information to my sys admin?